# Unable to save item fields in sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

A basic task but unable to achieve.
The data template is like this:

```
Comment --(template ID is {AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB})
 -Comment --section
   -Author --field
   -Comment Text   --field
```

I am creating a new item of that template as follows

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Sitecore.Data.Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
   Item parentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
   var template = masterDb.GetTemplate("{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}");            

   using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
      Item newItem = parentItem.Add(Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoNow, template);
      try
       {
        if (newItem != null)
         {
          newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
          newItem["Author"] = txtAuthor.Text;
          newItem["Comment Text"] = txtContent.Text;
          newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
         }
       }
      catch
       {
         //...log error
         newItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
       }
     }

     txtAuthor.Text = string.Empty;
     txtContent.Text = string.Empty;            
   }
```

The item gets saved with the timestamp as name, as I see in the content tree. Now when I try to see the values (Author, comment text), they are empty. So, I doubt , if they were saved in the first place.

Code to see comments, using another Usercontrol.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (!IsPostBack)
   {
     Database masterDb = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
     Item parentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
     var commentTemplate = masterDb.GetTemplate("{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}");
     var commentsList = parentItem.Children.Where(x => x.TemplateID == commentTemplate.ID);
     Item item = commentsList.FirstOrDefault();
     Response.Write(item["Author"] + "$$" + item["Comment Text"]);
   }
  }
```

The result is only

> $$

What am i missing here.

UPDATE:

The mistake was with the ID being referenced. I was using the `Template ID` of the 'Comment' data template. It has to be its `ID`.

Comment: You have different field name : Comment Author and Author.

Comment: Every time one creates a `try catch` without at least logging exception, a small kitten dies.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber. Sorry typo. Corrected now.

Comment: Are you running this code from your CD servers? Which has access to your master database...?

Comment: Item item = commentsList.FirstOrDefault(); can you check the id of the item,search for it in content editor and check field values. Also check language of that item when you save and read it.

Comment: There are no field values. Is there something wrong in the saving part..

Comment: I think you're mixing up your databases. You're trying to create an item in the web database using the template of the master. For comments you should consider using a separate comment Sitecore database, or first creating the comment in the master db and having it published to web either via workflow or manual publish.